Comparison Persian king's headquarters with the Holy of Holies in the Temple
In the story of Esther, a queen needed an invite into the king's inner room, despite the fact that it was the place for immediate family. Why was it done in the Persian palace? Can the ritual of providing an invite for a queen be compared to the permission to enter the Holy of Holies room in the Jewish Temple and what deeper meaning can one learn from it?

Huh? I thought everyone knew that any man or woman who comes to the king to the outer court without being called, their ruling is death, unless the king reaches out to them with his golden scepter so they can live.

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Please clarify what is a "high priest temple"?

The questioner is trying to equate the Persian king's inner throne room with the Holy of Holies. I just don't see it. Regardless -- this room wasn't a living space, which would be "for family"; it would be more like the Oval Office -- the most restricted of his work spaces. So no, not even family could waltz in. Especially when he had lots and lots of concubines. You're thinking in terms of today's relative parity between spouses; that's not what was going on then!
